# When calling an AJAX post request to rails db, the return data is a list of generic objects

Tags: php, sql, ruby-on-rails, ajax, highcharts

In my rails app in my view, I am trying to call an ajax query with parameters of date_from and date_to that then route to an action in my controller which will query through the dates in my database. It should return this range of dates in the "success" feedback in the ajax code, but instead it returns, for example, `"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"` if I were to pick a range of 1/1/2009 to 1/4/2009 (there are 4 objects for those 4 days). I would like the return data to be the objects and their column data in the database that I will eventually be able to use with a `Highcharts timeplot`. This is my code in question:

my JavaScript in the view:

```
function search() {
  var full_date_from = $( "#from" ).datepicker("getDate");
  var full_date_to = $( "#to" ).datepicker("getDate");

  var date_from = full_date_from.getMonth()+1 + "-" + full_date_from.getDate() + "-" + full_date_from.getFullYear();
  var date_to = full_date_to.getMonth()+1 + "-" + full_date_to.getDate() + "-" + full_date_to.getFullYear();

  $.ajax({
      url:"<%= url_for :controller => 'objects', :action => 'search' %>",
      data:'date_from=' + encodeURIComponent(date_from) + '&date_to=' + encodeURIComponent(date_to) + '&object_id=' + <%= @id %>,
      dataType: "json",
      cache:false,
      success:function (data) {
        $('#output').text(data); //outputs to <p id="#output"></p> on page
      }
  })
}
```

my search action in the controller:

```
def search
  @date_from = Date.strptime(params[:date_from], "%m-%d-%Y")
  @date_to = Date.strptime(params[:date_to], "%m-%d-%Y")
  @range = @object_data.where(:date => @date_from..@date_to)

  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @range }
  end
end
```

current output of `@range` array to `logger.debug()` if date_from is 2009-01-01 and date_to is 2009-01-04

```
#<River::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa6d4070>
```

each object of `@range` array in `logger.debug()` (I would like them to be string dates and I have tried `.to_s` and `.to_formatted_s(param)`

```
#<River:0xa595cf4>
#<River:0xa595b8c>
#<River:0xa595a38>
#<River:0xa595844>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the controller output you would be satisfied with?

Comment: Well actually, I would just like to use this output in the javascript of my view for use in a chart. The objects in the database table have a 'data' column, which would be turned into an array and used as the y of the chart, and then the other column, 'date', would be used as the x.

Comment: What about ``render :json => @range.map{|object| {data: object.data, date: object.date}}.to_json`` then? You should be able to iterate each object at client-side and ask for ``data`` or ``date`` of them.

Comment: I entered that into my action, but I still get [object Object]. Is there a certain way that I should be printing the object data on my web page? (I am printing it for now just for testing, and later I will put the object data into their respective arrays.)

Comment: Why don't you just take the ``data`` returned from controller (it is a parameter of your ``success`` callback) and iterate each of the ``[object]`` there? These object should have ``data`` and ``date`` attributes, so you should be able to access them like that:
``alert(data[0].date)`` or ``$('#output').text(data[0].date);``

Comment: Ahh ok I knew I was missing something. Thanks so much, if you post your comment as an answer I can select it as the "best answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this to return only desired attributes:

```
render :json => @range.select('data, date').to_json
```

or using map function:

```
render :json => @range.map{|object| {data: object.data, date: object.date}}.to_json
```

After getting the result in your success callback at client side, just iterate each of the objects inside of your data with something like that (coffeescript):

```
success: (data) ->
  for object in data
    $('#output').append(object.date);
```

You can also make sure that objects are received correctly with either console.log or alert:

```
console.log(data[0].date)
alert(data[0].date)
```